# Finding invariant factors of power matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am given the invariant factors of a real matrix $A$ which are $x^3+x^2 = x^2(x+1), x^8 - x^4 = x^4(x^2+1)(x-1)(x+1)$. Now I need to find the invariant factors of $A^2$. The first thing that throws me off is, why do we have a term $(x^2 +1)$ when the matrix is real? Wouldn't this imply that at some point in the matrix $(xI-A)$ we have an entry with complex numbers?

For solving it, I was thinking that since we can find the invariant factors of the matrix $A$ by transforming into Smith normal form the matrix $(xI - A)$, then to find the invariant factors we would need to transform to Smith normal form the matrix $(xI - A^2)$. But then, the matrix $A$ we can convert it into an upper triangular matrix $A'$ through elementary row operations. So, in the diagonal entries of the upper triangular matrix $A'$ we have the entries $0, 1,-1$ which correspond to the linear factors of the invariant factors. Then, squaring this matrix $A'$ the entries in the diagonal are $0,1$ and through elementary row operations we can transform the square of $A'$ back to $A^2$. Then, we can see that $(xI-A^2)$ would have invariant factors of the form $x^2(x-1), x^4(x^2-1)(x_1)^2$. I know this is not a precise argument, but I was wondering if this is the right approach to this problem? Can anyone give some hint to something better? Thanks!

Comment: The largest invariant factor is the minimal polynomial. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x^8 - x^4$ and so the minimal polynomial of $A^2$ is a *factor* of $x^4 - x^2$.